# Remove all zero bytes from file in Unix

Tags: shell, null

I've got a file of data from a prototype hardware RNG, however, for some reason it's producing a lot of `0x00` bytes. I want to delete all of these `0x00` bytes so I can test if the rest of the data is random.

How would I go about doing this in the terminal?

Comment: What has caused you to decide that the `0x00` bytes are ***not*** random?  **How** are you creating/writing that file?

Comment: @AndrewHenle to be honest, they looked like an artifact of something wrong with my transmission process. Removing the null bytes didn't help.  I just figured it was worth trying. The data is being produced by a quantum-random number generator I've made and being transmitted to the comp over UART. I've checked the data on a scope and it looks as I'd expect so something's going wrong in my FPGA that's converting the randomness to a bit stream

Comment: I'm reading it in from a serial port using cat

Comment: PNG is a binary format so you may not want to remove 0 bytes, but I got a messed up text file which surely doesn't need any zeroes.

Comment: @CsabaToth rng is a random number generator, not a typo

Comment: @ScottishTapWater My bad, I misread it, end of a very long day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tr -d '\0' <file >newfile
```

This deletes all nul bytes in the file `file` and saves the modified data in `newfile`.